# Put data from text boxes to an array list and to datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, arraylist

I'm trying to put data from text boxes in to an array list and to data grid view

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{       
   processing pr = new processing();
   pr.process = p.Text;
   pr.arrivaltime = Int32.Parse(AT.Text);
   pr.bursttime = Int32.Parse(BT.Text); 
   ArrayList Ar = new ArrayList();
   Ar.Add(pr);
   dataGridView1.DataSource = Ar;
}

private void BT_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

public class processing
{
   public string process { set; get; }
   public int arrivaltime { set; get; }
   public int bursttime { set; get; }
}
```

The problem now is that I want to make several data stored in an array and shown in a data grid view

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ArrayList` use `List<processing>` which would be type safe.

You need to declare one class level List and then add the items on your button click. Currently you are create a new list on each button click and that is why you end up with a single item in your list.

Also consider using .Net naming conventions for your class `processing`. It should start with upper case `P`

```
List<processing> list = new List<processing>(); // at class level.
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   processing pr = new processing();
   pr.process = p.Text;
   pr.arrivaltime = Int32.Parse(AT.Text);
   pr.bursttime = Int32.Parse(BT.Text); 
   list.Add(pr); //add item to class level list
   dataGridView1.DataSource = list; //update the data source
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much but  the problem is still appeared
i need to add more and more rows and put more data in array and it should be shown in datagridview in more rows

Comment: @AhmedHamzawy, are you sure you are not creating the list inside your button click event ?

Comment: I am not sure what is going on , you can put a break point and see if you have multiple items in your list